# Android reverse BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the original (or of similar size) byte array back from a Bitmap, after calling decodebytearray on a JPG image file?

I know of the Bitmap.compress method but it requires the compression quality which is not known.

Comment: you can set 100 as compression quality.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Bitmap.compress()` and `ByteArrayOutputStream.getBytes()`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
final byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.getBytes()
```

Comment: I'm trying to get back a byte array of similar length. With your method, a 5kb jpeg decoded into a bitmap then compressed can become 10kb.

Comment: Going through compression/decompression will not give you the exact same `byte[]` as source - mostly because, as you said, quality is unknown. No way around it that I'm aware of I'm afraid.